# Jasmine - How to write test case for AWS service authenticateUser?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular code in UI level and want to test following component code using Jasmine:

```
this.poolData = {
  UserPoolId: '<UserPoolId>',
  ClientId: '<ClientId>'
};
const userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
const authDetails = new AWSCognito.AuthenticationDetails({
  Username: this.username,
  Password: this.password
});
const cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoUser({
  Username: this.username,
  Pool: userPool
});
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
  onSuccess: (result) => {
    this.cognitoIdToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
  },
  onFailure: (err) => {
    alert('Invalid Username and/or Password');
    return;
  }
});
```

How can I write test case for this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You're supposed to test if your feature works as expected, not if a library is working well. That's not your job.

What you must do is mock your dependency. It seems that you directly use the library, so use a spy for that.

```js
import * as AWS from 'your-dependency';

it('should create a Cognito User Pool', () => {
  spyOn(AWS.AWSCognito, 'CognitoUserPool');

  feature.myMethod();

  expect(AWS.AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool).toHaveBeenCalledWith(feature.poolData);
});
```

I'll let you do the rest, this was just an example.

If you need to return something, for instance when you create an object, you can mock it like this :

```js
spyOn(AWS.AWSCognito, 'CognitoUser').and.returnValue({
  authenticateUser: (details, success, failure) => null
});
```

Comment: I am new for Jasmine. Please elaborate and give answer.

Comment: I did elaborate and I did "give answer". You're supposed to test it now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added this code. I am getting Error: <spyOn> : CognitoUser is not declared writable or has no setter. Please suggest how to resolve.

Comment: `Object.assignProperty(AWS.AWSCognito, 'CognitoUser', { writable: true, value: {}})`

Comment: I am using 'your-dependency' as 'amazon-cognito-identity-js', after adding this showing tslint error as - Property 'assignProperty' does not exist on type 'typeof "amazon-cognito-identity-js"'

Comment: Just copy paste this line of code in the code i already gave you. Don't do anything else.

Comment: Getting error TS2339: Property 'assignProperty' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: If you have an issue with this, then you have an issue in your project structure, not in your tests. **[defineProperty is pretty much a standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/defineProperty)**.